# histogram plot from a csv file in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image: My expected image] [image: Matlab is giving this plot]I really need help in the histogram plot from a csv file format. When I searched in the internet for histogram it was suggested hist function. In the following example hist is working only for x or y but not both. My expected plot is shown in figure1 red plot. By matlab code I am getting plot as shown in figure2 blue plot.

```
close all
data = csvread('mc_10000_better.csv',4); % Read the data
y = data(:,1) ; 
x = data(:,2) ; 
plot(y,x)
xlabel('Samples')
ylabel('Current')
```

Comment: What are your expected results? Please include a [mre]. I don't see any instance of `hist` or the preferred [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html). Note that the tag [tag:matlab-guide] is for the MATLAB GUIDE interactive GUI editor. Please read the tag descriptions.

Comment: you are probably looking at `plot(x); hold on; plot(y)` no? I guess the csv values are the histogram counts.

Comment: @beaker I have updated the question. My expected plot is in red colour bar plot.  But I was getting the plot as shown in blue figure. Can you please help me in this

Comment: `plot( y, x, 'ro' )`, where *r* stands for red and *o* stands for circle.

Comment: @marsei I will try . thank you.